# Remove duplicates before insert sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have temporary table #tempRD and I am trying to insert the resultset into a table as follows:

```
insert into Routing (RoutingKeyID, LocationID, Data, ServiceID, CountryID)
   select 
       rk.ID, rd.LocationID, rd.Data, rd.service, rd.CountryID
   from 
       #tempRD rd
   inner join 
       RoutingKey rk on rk.serviceID = @ID and rk.Name=rd.[Key]
```

Now when this happens I get duplicate key errors

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Routing' with unique index 'UIX_Routing_RoutingKeyID_CountryID'. The duplicate key value is (51, 433)

How can I check if a row by `routingkeyid` and `countryid` already exists before I do an insert?

I have used a cursor to do this but it takes a long long time.

Comment: Can you try: SELECT RoutingKeyID, LocationID, Data, ServiceID, CountryID, RoutingKey.CountryID from Routing INNER JOIN RoutingKey ON ROuting.CountryID=RoutingKey.CountryID Sort By Routing.CountryID Order By Routing.CountryID desc;

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into Routing (RoutingKeyID, LocationID, Data, ServiceID, CountryID)

select *
from (
select rk.ID, rd.LocationID, rd.Data, rd.service, rd.CountryID, rank() over(partition by rk.ID, rd.CountryID order by rd.LocationID, rd.Data, rd.Service) as rnk
from #tempRD rd
inner join RoutingKey rk on rk.serviceID = @ID and rk.Name=rd.[Key]
) a
where rnk = 1
```

With the `rank() over(partition by ... order by ....)` you create a ranking of records that have a duplicate combination of `rk.ID, rd.CountryID`. At the end you apply the WHERE-clause to only use the first occurrence of the combination.

You could also use a `select distinct` if the other fields are also duplicates. I didn't try the code, there may be typo's ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
INSERT INTO 
    Routing (
        RoutingKeyID, 
        LocationID, 
        Data, 
        ServiceID, 
        CountryID)
SELECT 
    rk.ID, 
    rd.LocationID, 
    rd.Data, 
    rd.[service], 
    rd.CountryID
FROM 
    #tempRD rd
    INNER JOIN RoutingKey rk ON rk.serviceID = @ID AND rk.Name = rd.[Key]
    LEFT JOIN Routing r ON r.RoutingKeyID = rk.ID AND r.CountryID = rd.CountryID
WHERE
    r.RoutingKeyID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Row_number` window function you can find the duplicates. Note i have ordered by id desc to get the latest record of duplicate.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER(partition BY RoutingKeyID, CountryID ORDER BY id DESC) rn,
                rk.ID,
                rd.LocationID,
                rd.Data,
                rd.service,
                rd.CountryID
         FROM   #tempRD rd)
INSERT INTO Routing
            (RoutingKeyID,LocationID,Data,ServiceID,CountryID)
SELECT rk.ID,
       rd.LocationID,
       rd.Data,
       rd.service,
       rd.CountryID
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use something like

```
MERGE INTO Routing 
USING (SELECT @RoutingKeyID, @LocationID, @Data, @ServiceID, @CountryID) AS source (RoutingKeyID, LocationID, Data, ServiceID, CountryID)
ON (Routing.RoutingKeyID= source.RoutingKeyID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (RoutingKeyID, LocationID, Data, ServiceID, CountryID)
VALUES (source.RoutingKeyID, source.LocationID, source.Data, source.ServiceID, source.CountryID)
```